# What are the standings for the different alien species?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Is there a list anywhere (in-game or out) of the standings you can have with the aliens? Also, are the standings the same per species, or does each one have it's own names?

Comment: The Vy'Keen standings are the best. I'm currently in a Special Relationship with them.

Comment: I'm currently a "Traveller of the Atlas" with Korvax, not sure about everything else.

Comment: Judging by those two comments and the fact I've never seen the "Traveler of the Atlas" I'd say each species has their own standings.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen no official lists anywhere so I can't provide the actual levels.

However,  each race has it's own names and each list goes along with the culture of the particular society.

- The Korvax list uses terms that seem to refer to you in a research perspective (i.e. you ARE the one being researched)
- The Gek list refers to you from the perspective of trade ("partner" for example)
- The Vy'keen seem to be the only ones that list you based on your personal merits, but this may just be your combat ability and/or usefulness to them from a combat perspective.

Answer (score 2):

The Korvax seem to be the religious race, with their highest standing being **Traveler of the Atlas**.

The Gek are the economic race and their highest standing is **Partner**.

Lastly, the Vy'keen are the typical war-like race and their highest standing is **Special Relationship**.

Comment: Oh man, really? I was really hoping there were some more higher ones... I've got top tier relationship status with each race already - even the Gek, who I've been actively avoiding for roleplay purposes. Seems like it's way too easy to increase your standing.

Comment: This is purely from experience, but in each case I reached those tiers and had at least 10 "relationship increased" events occur without it changing, but hitting 1-2 "relationship decreased" events would knock it down a tier, so it seems like these are the highest ranks for each.